# icon image in the "add bookmark" screen in IPhone

Tags: mobile

[image: a busy cat]

Hi,

I have a web application specific for mobile. I am testing the application using IPhone.
I want to set up the image icon displayed in the left panel as my screen above.

Could you please advise how to achieve?

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML that needs to be modified.

Comment: I am asking a approach to have that. I am going to use this but it doesn't work. <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://luongto/Images/icon_58x58.png" /> Thank you.